# Is it possible to create a deterministic secure random string based on some input from the client?

Tags: java

Two scenarios:
Say my user provides me the following:

```
long firstId;
long secondId;
```

or

```
UUID firstId;
long secondId;
```

and I have a variable to define a secret string:

```
private String mySecret = "2m75eB4xmAtMrz5cYQdSCch9R5R3xU6G";
```

Can I use the user inputs to generate a secure random string on the fly without hardcoding a string in the code (which seems pretty insecure)? If my program restarts and I provide the same input, I should get the same secret generated.

Comment: It sounds like you want to hash a password?

Comment: Use any symmetric encryption algorithm. AES, Twofish or 3DES. As long as the key and the user input are identical, you will get consistent output. Other options exist. Like [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-passwords.html) (which makes this much easier).

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about security you should give some info about the context and what are you tryng to do, for random string i suggest a digest:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] encodedhash = digest.digest(
  originalString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

private static String bytesToHex(byte[] hash) {
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
    String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & hash[i]);
    if(hex.length() == 1) hexString.append('0');
        hexString.append(hex);
    }
    return hexString.toString();
}
```

You can use as input string something like:

```
String input = mySecret + (firstId + secondId);
```

Given the same input this digest will give you always the same result but you would be exposed to an attack that is called *dictionary attack*, in this way a cracker that know what algorithm you are using "sha-256" can retrieve the original secret from the digest.